# Is it better to use heading tags for typography or use P tags and add custom classes?

Tags: fonts, typography

I'm trying to find the best system to organize my typography:

Method A:

```
<h1> hello</h1>
```

or

Method B:

```
<p class="as_large_as_H1"> Hello </p>
```

Witch one is better, any other guidelines to proper typography usage on templating for the web?

My fonts are all over the place, and trying to consolidate some kind of system.

Comment: For refactoring of existing project, method B is more sensible as it offers bigger level of control. This is example of that approach: http://csswizardry.com/2016/02/managing-typography-on-large-apps/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_headings.asp)...

> Use HTML headings for headings only. Don't use headings to make text
> BIG or bold. Search engines use your headings to index the structure
> and content of your web pages.

If the text is a title, subtitle, section marker, etc then use a heading tag. If it's just cool typography, use CSS to enlarge the text.

## Edit

If you're looking to consolidate your text styles, it may be a good idea to choose a few font sizes to use universally and give them modifier classes:

```
.small-font  { font-size: 0.75rem; }
.normal-font { font-size: 1rem;    }
.large-font  { font-size: 1.25rem; }
.huge-font   { font-size: 1.5rem;  }
```

Comment: Good answer, but will wait for more feedback, thanks ;)